# Check Out - Prevent other users from checking out and checking in is not shown

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, locking, source-control-explorer, vcs-checkout

When I try to check out a file I am not getting the option "Check Out - Prevent other users from checking out and checking in" however from a different system when I connect to the same TFS using the same credentials, this option is shown in the drop down for the same file. Please let me know what could be the reason  ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you Source Control environment settings. You should have the option to prompt for a lock.
[image: Prompt for lock on checkout]